# php foreach inside an echo which is html code

Tags: php, html, function, foreach, echo

I'm in trouble with some php output. I'm already echoing out some html and that works fine! Those are groups that should contain more elements -> I need to output some anchor elements  dynamically from the database inside each group. And that needs to happen inside the html which is already an echo. I thought I could put another foreach loop inside there...I tried and tried but I can't figure it out...I always get an error.

Dreamweaver is telling me, that this part

```
foreach($links as $item){echo $item;}
```

is definitely wrong (syntax error), but I don't know how to put it in there correctly.

Thanks for your help!

```
echo '<li id="todo-'.$this->data['id'].'" class="todo">     
    <div class="group__name"><div class="text input_groupname">'.$this->data['text'].'</div>       
    </div>
    <div class="group_more_button">more <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-down"></i></div>
    <div class="group_list_wrapper">
            <div class="group__list_SortMe">'


    '.foreach($links as $item){
        echo $item;
    }.'

               '<div class="add_button">
                  <div class="plus open">
                       <span></span>
                       <span></span>
                  </div> 
               </div> 
            </div> <!-- group__list_SortMe-->
    </div> <!-- group_list_wrapper--> 

            <div class="actions">
                <a href="#" class="edit">Edit</a>
                <a href="#" class="deleteICON">Delete</a>
            </div>

        </li>';
```

Comment: You don't have a semicolon after the first echo. You have to close the first echo and start a new echo after the loop

Comment: another solution would be to build the string up inside a variable first, and then just echo the variable once at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Or this?...just for readibility sake.  I have to jump in and out of PHP to make such long strings logical to me.

```
<li id="todo-<?=$this->data['id']?>" class="todo">     
    <div class="group__name"><div class="text input_groupname"><?=$this->data['text']?></div>       
    <div class="group_more_button">more <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-down"></i></div>
    <div class="group_list_wrapper">
        <div class="group__list_SortMe">


        <?php 
        foreach($links as $item){
            echo $item;
        }
        ?>
            <div class="add_button">
                <div class="plus open">
                    <span></span>
                    <span></span>
                 </div> 
             </div> 
          </div> <!-- group__list_SortMe-->
    </div> <!-- group_list_wrapper--> 

    <div class="actions">
        <a href="#" class="edit">Edit</a>
        <a href="#" class="deleteICON">Delete</a>
    </div>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

`foreach` returns nothing (AFAIK), you chaining it in your `echo` wouldn't do anything. Finish the `echo`, and begin the `foreach` call on a new line. After that, start a new `echo`. Like this:

```
echo "blah blah this is a whole lotta text ";

foreach($links as $item){
    echo $item;
}

echo " and this is some more text";
```

Comment: Too bad...it's still not working. Now I'm getting an error message: 'Catchable fatal error: Method () must return a string value' ...using the __toString method

Answer (score 0):

Why so complicated? Try it like this:

```
echo '<li id="todo-'.$this->data['id'].'" class="todo">     
<div class="group__name"><div class="text input_groupname">'.$this->data['text'].'</div>       
</div>
<div class="group_more_button">more <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-down"></i></div>
<div class="group_list_wrapper">
        <div class="group__list_SortMe">';

foreach($links as $item){
    echo $item;
}

echo '<div class="add_button">
              <div class="plus open">
                   <span></span>
                   <span></span>
              </div> 
           </div> 
        </div> <!-- group__list_SortMe-->
</div> <!-- group_list_wrapper--> 

        <div class="actions">
            <a href="#" class="edit">Edit</a>
            <a href="#" class="deleteICON">Delete</a>
        </div>

    </li>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than `echo` HTML, why don't you separate it? It helps performance having to `echo` less.

```
<li id="todo-<?php echo $this->data['id']; ?>" class="todo">     
    <div class="group__name"><div class="text input_groupname"><?php echo $this->data['text']; ?></div>       
    </div>
    <div class="group_more_button">more <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-down"></i></div>
    <div class="group_list_wrapper">
        <div class="group__list_SortMe">
<?php
foreach($links as $item)
{
    echo $item;
}
?>

            <div class="add_button">
                <div class="plus open">
                    <span></span>
                    <span></span>
                </div> 
            </div> 
        </div> <!-- group__list_SortMe-->
    </div> <!-- group_list_wrapper--> 
    <div class="actions">
        <a href="#" class="edit">Edit</a>
        <a href="#" class="deleteICON">Delete</a>
    </div>
</li>';
```

Answer (score 0):

To be a bit more explicit, foreach is a keyword that cannot be concatenated (`echo"x". foreach () {} ."y";`) into a string. It requires its own block statement to execute properly.

```
echo("<tag>");

foreach ($items as $item) {
    /* execute logic here */
}

echo("</tag>");
```

Answer (score 0):

Below i correct your code and hope it will work fine.

```
    echo '
<li id="todo-'.$this->data['id'].'" class="todo">     
<div class="group__name"><div class="text input_groupname">'.$this->data['text'].'</div>       
</div>
<div class="group_more_button">more <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-down"></i></div>
<div class="group_list_wrapper">
        <div class="group__list_SortMe">

';
foreach($links as $item){
    echo $item;
}

    echo '<div class="add_button">
                <div class="plus open">
                    <span></span>
                    <span></span>
                </div> 
            </div> 
        </div> <!-- group__list_SortMe-->
</div> <!-- group_list_wrapper--> 

        <div class="actions">
            <a href="#" class="edit">Edit</a>
            <a href="#" class="deleteICON">Delete</a>
        </div>

    </li>';
```

Problem was that , you have to close echo before foreach and after foreach start a new echo. same logic is working fine with my code. Hope this also.